# Leaflet: A way to show information of overlapping polygon of the same layer?

Tags: leaflet, popup

I have a polygon layer with overlapping polygons. When clicking on a spot with more than one polygon eg. overlapping polygons, the popup shows the property of only one feature (the topmost?). Is there a way to show the content of the same attribute of several objects in one popup?

Comment: SO you have an onclick event that basically does a point in polygon, and builds an array.Just say you have 1 record with 7 fields, the popup is OK, but say you have 4 records, the popup is a div will now have all 28 fields. It's too big, put them in a picklick/combobox and you don't know which record you are looking at. It might be better to have the results go to a table and on-select have the polygon highlight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my question needs some elaboration. I have a geojson-polygon-layer which I display with leaflet in the brwser. OnEachFeature and layer.bindPopup provides a nice way to show the property of a feature, eg.
onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){layer.bindPopup(   '<strong>' + 'id: ' + feature.properties.id + '</strong><br/>'    + 'art: ' + feature.properties.art + '<br/>'+ 'arttxt: ' + feature.properties.arttxt)}}).addTo(map);
But in case there are overlapping features and a common area is clicked only the propperty if one featrue is shown. I should have all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onEachFeature is the issue, you tied a single popup to each feature and you can only click on one at a time. The traditional popup will not work. To select more then one polygon, you have to use a map on Click, and grab the coordinates and use them in a point in poly loop, this will let you grab all the polygons the point touches.

Now you can open a div like a popup and put the results in it. Or put a table on a side panel and put the results there. It's not a real popup solution but you are not clicking on a single polygon.